# For acute $\theta$, write $\cot\theta$ in terms of $\sin\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> For acute $\theta$, write $\cot\theta$ in terms of $\sin\theta$.

I know that's $\cot\theta = \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ but why is the answer $\cot\theta= \frac{\sqrt {1-\sin^2\theta}}{\sin\theta}$?

Comment: Because $${\sin ^2}\theta  + {\cos ^2}\theta  = 1$$

Comment: We cannot quite express $\cot\theta$ in terms of $\sin\theta$. For depending on what quadrant $\theta$ is in, we have $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ or $\cos\theta=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$. But in the first quadrant it is $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Pythagorean identity:$$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta) = 1$$Subtracting $\sin^2(\theta)$ from both sides:$$\cos^2(\theta) = 1-\sin^2(\theta) $$ Because $\theta$ is acute ($0^\circ < \theta < 90^\circ$) we can take the square root of both sides and keep all of our signs the same ($\sin, \cos, \tan$ are all positive when $\theta$ is acute) so we now have:$$\cos(\theta) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$$

So from $\cot(\theta) = \dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$: $$\boxed{\cot(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}}{\sin(\theta)}}$$